# Image gallery saver lock the main thread flutter

Tags: image, flutter, gallery

I'm used [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin for capture image and after image captured I saved image to gallery using [image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver). My problem is that when Image Gallery Saver save the image to gallery it locked the main UI thread for some time and my camera not response for some seconds. I want to capture images continuously. I used isolate and compute but it's not woking with it. I think Image Gallery Saver work only main thread. What is the best way to save image to gallery and capture images continuously or any other alternative is there?

I tried with this

```
saveToLocale(Uint8List bytes) async {
compute(ImageGallerySaver.saveImage, bytes);
}
```

and this

```
saveToLocale(Uint8List bytes) async {
ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(bytes).then((result) {});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) solved my probleam. Its work without locking the main UI thread

```
Future<void> saveToLocale(String url) async {
  await GallerySaver.saveImage(url, albumName: "Abc");
}
```